# show rootview controller (uitableviewcontroller subclass) in splitview in portrait mode

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios4, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to show rootview controller(uitableviewcontroller sublass) in splitview in portrait mode which is by default hidden.when i switch to landscape mode its visible but i want to show this in portrait mode also.

thanx for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [APSplitViewController](https://github.com/slatvick/APSplitViewController).

Comment: Getting a 404 from github.  This repo M=must've been taken down.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible using the standard UISplitViewController class. Apple has a private API they use to do this same thing in the Settings app. Take a look at this [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController) which should allow you to achieve the same effect without breaking the private API rules.